# FileMaker SQL queries via ODBC Table doesn't return a result

Tags: php, sql, filemaker

I have this seriously strange issue. I have 4 tables in a FileMaker 12 file: Issues, Articles, FMBM, Ads. I have 2 methods in my results class, one writes a series of serial IDs to each of these tables, the other queries those tables. The method that writes the serial ID's works perfectly. The method that queries the tables works for 3 of the 4 tables (Articles, FMBM, Ads) but returns no result set for Issues.

I have checked permissions, but as this is the admin user, it has full access to all and there are no table specific or layout specific restrictions (again, it's the admin). Oddly enough, I thought maybe it's the query, but when I run "SELECT * FROM Issues" in my ODBC Query Tool, it returns the appropriate results. It's just baffling to me that the setKeys() method works perfectly but the view method ONLY fails on Issues.

The Model:

```
class Application_Model_Results {

    public $keys;
    public $odbc;
    public $comp = array('Issues', 'Articles', 'Ads', 'FMBM');
    public $existing = array();

    function setKeys() {
        $this->odbc = 'Migrator';
        $obj = new Application_Model_Utilities();
        $obj->name = $this->odbc;
        $config = $obj->getElements();
        $conn = odbc_connect($this->odbc, $config['user'], $config['password']);
        if (!$conn) {
            exit("Connection failed: -> " . $this->odbc);
        }
        foreach ($this->comp as $c) {
            $sql = "SELECT Serial_ID FROM " . $c;
            $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
            if (!$rs) {
                exit("Error in SQL");
            }
            while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
                $this->existing[] = odbc_result($rs, 'Serial_ID');
            }
            if (in_array(true, $this->keys[$c])) {
                foreach ($this->keys[$c] as $v) {
                    if (!in_array($v, $this->existing)) {
                        $iSql = "INSERT INTO " . $c . "(Serial_ID) VALUES('$v')";
                        odbc_exec($conn, $iSql);
                        $obj->output = 'Inserted Serial_ID: ' . $v . ' into table ' . $c;
                        $obj->logger();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function getResults($table) {
        $this->odbc = 'Migrator';
        $obj = new Application_Model_Utilities();
        $obj->name = $this->odbc;
        $config = $obj->getElements();
        $conn = odbc_connect($this->odbc, $config['user'], $config['password']);
        if (!$conn) {
            exit("Connection failed: -> " . $this->odbc);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
        while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
            $results[odbc_result($rs, 'Serial_ID')] = odbc_fetch_array($rs);
        }
        return $results;
    }

}
```

The Controller:

```
public function viewAction()
    {
        $results = new Application_Model_Results();
        $result = $results->getResults('Issues');
        $page = $this->_getParam('page', 1);
        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(1);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
    }
```

Note: If scrap the view code, and just write:

```
<?php 

$conn = odbc_connect('Migrator', 'admin', '********');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Issues";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
    print_r(odbc_result_all($rs));
}
```

I get no rows returned.

EDIT:

Culprit has been found:

```
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $results[odbc_result($rs, 'Serial_ID')] = odbc_fetch_array($rs);
}
```

Now, I am working on a solution that grabs each result row and pushes it to an associative array, the problem is, on the view, I need to dump everything, not have to use odbc_result($rs, ) for every single field.

Comment: In your scrap view, you're printing the string 'Found it' in your while loop, but are you able to output the actual results from the row fetch?

Comment: Was testing to see if anything at all was getting through, it returns no rows found and since that is a result, prints the found it.

I'm finding it so very odd that it's just the issues table that wont return results, even though I can write to it. I've deleted it, recreated it, copied it,  scrapped the file and rebuilt it, nada

Comment: Yeah, that is really odd. It's probably not this, but your updated scrap view has a closing parens missing: `print_r(odbc_fetch_all($rs));`. That may make a difference at least for the scrap view.

Comment: The fact that you're "getting" a result but it's empty makes me wonder if there's anything in the database table that's not able to be returned via odbc. Do you have any container fields in that table? Also, can you return just one field like an ID field?

Comment: No containers, just text and numbers. Can't return any fields at all from this table. Another oddity, I created a new table and added 4 fields( 3 text, 1 number), created a record and populated some random values. I can return the serial ID of that record, but the rest returns bool(false).

Comment: odbc_fetch_all isn't a php function that I know of. Try following the pattern used in this post as far as executing and returning the results. See if that sheds any light: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-result-all.php#98302

Comment: You are right, I typed that off the top of my head from my phone, it's supposed to be odbc_result_all

Comment: Blergh, yeah I'm stumped too :/

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz I know what the culprit is.... $results[odbc_result($rs, 'Serial_ID')] = odbc_fetch_array($rs); This is causing the while loop to only retrieve every other record returned by odbc_exec(). When I just do a print_r(odbc_result($rs, 'Serial_ID') in the while loop, all records are returned from all tables.

Comment: Cool, so are you able to return the whole table result too now?

Comment: Only when doing the odbc_fetch_result() with a specified field, but I need to get all fields and values shoved into an array to parse by paginator, so working on that now. When I have an actual working result, I'll post it up so you can see with a description of the oddity. @ChrisSchmitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, my nightmare is over:

```
public function getResults($table) {
        $obj = new Application_Model_Utilities();
        $obj->name = $this->odbc;
        $config = $obj->getElements();
        $conn = odbc_connect($this->odbc, $config['user'], $config['password']);
        if (!$conn) {
            exit("Connection failed: -> " . $this->odbc);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
        $obj->output = 'Running query: ' . $sql;
        $obj->logger();
        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
        $obj->output = 'Results found: ' . odbc_num_rows($rs);
        $obj->logger();
        $results = array();
        $i = 1;
        while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){
            $results[] = odbc_fetch_array($rs, $i);
            $i++;
        }


        return $results;
    }
```

This returns an associative array that I can actually loop through.

NOTE: in this instance, any use of odbc_fetch_array, odbc_fetch_object, odbc_fetch_into, unless I forced the odbc_fetch_array to have a row value, would only reutrn every other result, not all results and then would die on the view unless I specifically called for a field value, and even then, the same value persisted across all paginated records.